# Progressive Web App, I am trying to maintain same screen when minimize or maximize in iphone

Tags: progressive-web-apps

In Android, When I minimize and maximize, the app maintain the same screen what I saw previously.
In iPhone, When I minimize and maximize, The app not maintaining the same screen. reload from home screen.

Answer (score 1):

Full screen implementation web app for IOS is quite different when compared to that of android. If you are running your web app in full screen mode in IOS, minimize the app and maximize again, IOS considers it as fresh start so all the session cookies(cookies having session as timeout) will be cleared on minimize. so if you have cookies related to session, they all will be cleared. However you can try implementing html caching(using cache.manifest) to cache the pages. I've not personally implemented this but it might help. All the best